# GCP Cloud run (with python) logging to cloud logging

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to use cloud run for receiving millions of log messages through HTTPS (streaming) and sending them to cloud logging.

But I found there is some loss of data, the number of messages in cloud logging is less than cloud run receiving.

This is the sample code that I tried,

```
# unzip data
data = gzip.decompress(request.data)

# split by lines
logs = data.decode('UTF-8').split('\n')

# output the logs
log_cnt = 0
for log in logs:
    try:
        # output to jsonPayload
        print(json.dumps(json.loads(log_str))
        log_cnt += 1
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(F"messsage: {str(e)}")
```

and If I compare the log_cnt and number of logs in cloud logging, the log_cnt is more. So some print is not finishing the delivering message.

I tried using logging API instead of print(), but the number of logs is too many for sending using logging API (12,000 calls limit for a minute), so it causes the latency very bad, and could not handle requests stably.

I dought the moving number of instances might cause it, so I test when the active instance is not changed, but still, 3-5% of messages are missing.

Is there something I can do for sending all of the messages to cloud logging without any loss?

(updated)

the line of data looks like this, (around 1kb)

```
{"key1": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key2": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key3": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key4": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key5": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key6": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key7": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key8": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key9": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key10": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key11": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key12": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key13": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key14": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key15": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key16": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key17": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key18": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key19": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key20": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key21": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key22": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key23": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key24": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key26": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key27": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key28": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key29": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key30": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key31": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key32": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key33": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key34": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN","key35": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend you to use the [entries.write API](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/write) that allow you to write a bulk of entries in the same time. Have a look on my test in the API explorer

[image]

It could solve the JSON format and the multiple write in the same time. Have a try with this API and let me know if it's better for you. If not, I will remove this answer!